# webclient bugging out or what?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

hi
I ran my project yesterday just fine, but today when I ran the same code it hangs on WebClient.DownloadFile() and eventually times out with this error message:
 "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll"

So I tried running only the webclient in a new project, downloading from a hardcoded url that I know is up like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile("http://www.ashersarlin.com/cartoons/officerap2.gif", "pic.gif");
    }
```

Same thing happens. It creates an empty file "pic.gif" but times out eventually.

I could use some pointers. I'm new to .NET and have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: what's the exception message? The code is fine, so it looks like you can't get out to the Internet - are you using a proxy by chance?

Comment: If the code hasn't changed, then something external has.  What are the details of the exception? Are you able to access that URL from a web browser?

Comment: not using a proxy, I can access the url from a browser. All I get apart from what I posted in the q is "Additional information: The operation has timed out" ... can I get any more details from it?

Answer (score 3):

Your exact code works for me...

Perhaps your default proxy is messed up?

Suggestions:

- Print out the detail of the `WebException` - it may give more hints
- Use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to see what's going on at the network level. That should show you if it's trying to connect, what it's getting back etc.

Comment: uhm yea... I restarted the PC and it started working. No idea what happened. Weird thing was that I could still download a file from my local web server.